# handling exceptions in loops with user ouput

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have been struggling with this issue for a while. I would like to catch any exceptions in my foreach loop and continue to loop through any other data, but I would also like to let the user know what failed via the client side. Also all calls to my functions are done through ajax calls.

For this I have been using the following:

```
  $errors = array();
  foreach ($form as $index => $data) {
   try{
    //continue, item has been processed
   }catch(exception $e){
      //add some data to the errors array
      array_push($data, $errors);
   }
  }
  return Response::json($errors);
```

this allows me to then get the items that failed in my ajax response and notify the user.

i'm not sure if this is best practice or if there is a better way to do this? is there a better way to return errors to the client side without aborting the loop?

Some background info:
I am mostly wanting this for use when I am adding data to my database.

Comment: usually you would write your own validation with your own error messages, which would make more sense to the user than php or mysql errors - "this email is already registered" is much more useful than "Duplicate entry 'hello@gmail.com' for key 'PRIMARY'.

Comment: yes i understand that, I would return "blah blah was not able to be added to the database" or something like that. I am asking what is the best way to handle these while in a loop. not how to check if a user exists.

Comment: my point was you are catching exceptions as part of the validation. Exceptions should be for exceptional cases - you should instead perform your own validation code. However your technique of pushing errors to an array and then json encoding it is fine.

Comment: This looks good to me. I'd probably loop through the errors array and call Log::error($error) on each so they show up in your application log in addition to the json response.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to return raw messages from Exceptions to the user, append the message with `$data['error'] = $e->getMessage();` to your data array, like

```
$errors = array();
foreach ($form as $index => $data) {
   try{
    //continue, item has been processed
   }catch(exception $e){
      // append exception message to data
      $data['error'] = $e->getMessage();

      //add some data to the errors array
      array_push($data, $errors);
   }
 }
 return Response::json($errors);
```

but is better write your own validation with your own error messages.